# How can I change the bulb in my 97 Subaru Legacy shifter?

Tags: lights

The light which illuminates the gear labels from beneath, `P R N D 1 2 3`, is out on my '97 Subaru Legacy. It's quite annoying at night. I've had to memorize the order of the gears, which is a truly awful burden to bear.

So I took apart the shifter and shifter assembly to get at the bulb to replace it, only to find that I couldn't remove the old one. It didn't twist out nor pull out, as far as I could tell.

Is there some trick to removing these that I'm not seeing? I couldn't get the cable out underneath, either. Here it is:

[image]

Comment: Pull like hell it will come out! These are called peanut bulbs and pull straight out of the socket.

Comment: I gave up, I think I'm going to do it with pliers. I pulled like hell and nothing happened except my fingers slipping off; I'm afraid if I squeeze any harder it'll shatter in my fingers; last thing I want.

Comment: Rock it side to side in both directions, then pull like hell.

Comment: I tried that :( Maybe I should post a video of it.

Comment: Its possible the bulb is permanent with the plastic socket, never run across this but is possible, contact a Subaru dealer and see if they offer the replacement bulb or assembly. Assembly would indicate they are not separate.

Comment: I have already purchased a new bulb from them, so it's just me being unable to get it out.

Comment: Buy a new socket and be done.

Answer (score 3):

Those 5w bulbs normally pull straight out of their holders, perhaps it has corroded in there. Even if you break the bulb just hold the holder securely in a vice (wear eye protection) and carefully dig out the rest of the glass bulb, being careful not the damage the bulb contacts.

If you do damage the contacts you can buy the new bulb holders cheaply.

Comment: If the glass comes off you might be able to pull the cap out with a needle-nose pliers. You could try working a small, thin flathead screwdriver into the gap between the base and the cap (the metal part with the contacts) and see if you can break the corrosion. Make sure to clean the corrosion off before putting in a new one.

Answer (score 2):

The bulb comes out of the black holder. It is held in place by a pinch connection at the base. It looks like this when out of the holder.

[image]

I have had the best luck rocking the bulb side-to-side to get it to come out.

Press a new bulb in firmly and test it.